# Dynamically rendering child components in Vue.js v2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm building a faceted search system in VueJS. The general idea is simple:

A `FilterGroup` component contains the overall filter logic. This component accepts a variety of child components, e.g. `AttributeXYZFilter`. These child components are responsible for providing conditions which `FilterGroup` will use to filter a collection of items.

An example usage of this system looks like this:

```
<template>
  <FilterGroup :items="items">
    <ABCFilter/>
    <XYZFilter/>
    <AnotherFilter/>
  </FilterGroup>
</template>
```

My problem is as follows:

The filter components should be rendered by `FilterGroup` in a specific layout. Also, `FilterGroup` should provide the filter components with some additional data using props.

To avoid unnecessary coupling, `FilterGroup` should not know which filters will be rendered. Each filter adheres to a common specification/interface (implemented using mixins). Each filter has its own UI template.

How can this be implemented?

I tried using slots, but I can't figure out how to custom render the child components. If no slot is being used, `this.$children` is empty so I don't know which filters to render.

I could provide the filters like this:

```
<template>
  <FilterGroup :items="items" :filters="['ABCFilter', 'XYZFilter']/>
</template>
```

Then `FilterGroup` could dynamically import and render the filter components. It would even be possible to pass additional data. However, I think the resulting API is less readable and developer-friendly.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Using props, not slots, is the correct approach. Slots are not children.

Answer (score 4):

I think you would like to use [Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) for that. This allows you dynamically render a (child) component based on the data. In your example the filters.

The `:is="ComponentName"` defines the component that should be rendered. Use a `props` to pass down the data:

```
<template>
    <div class="app-body row">
        <template v-for="(child, index) in children">
            <component :is="child.viewName" :key="child.name" :data="child.data"></component>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does using scoped-slots solve your problem? You can then provide custom render the child components.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3w8drxuj/1/)

```
Vue.component('filter-group', {
  template: `
  <div class="filter-group">
    <slot :items="items">
    </slot>
  </div>
  `,
  data: function() {
    return {
      items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('filter-a', {
  template: `
  <div class="filter-a">
    filter a: {{ items }}
  </div>
  `,
  props: ['items']
})

Vue.component('filter-b', {
  template: `
  <div class="filter-b">
    filter b: {{ items }}
  </div>
  `,
  props: ['items']
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```